# Find variance between two rows in the same column that share attribute in different column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do as the title suggests. We have different stages in our manufacturing process. At each stage we count the items and this number usually drops as we get have to scrap some inventory at each stage. I am trying to find this variance.

The processes are sorted by ascending stages and the work order. Sorry about the poor formatting, I didn't know a better way to illustrate

```
ORDER     STAGE     PROCESS      COUNT
25252      1         Build        202
25252      2       Laser Cut      201
25252      3       Packaging      200
25260      1         Build       1500
25260      2       Laser Cut     1497
25260      3       Packaging     1495
```

So I'm trying to add another column that shows the variance in count, but limited to just that order. That way it won't show the difference between the row that has the 200 count and the row that has 1500 count. In this case the column would show

```
Null
-1
-1
Null
-3
-2
```

Sorry again for the poor formatting. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a Lag function to find the variance. Sorry for my lack of information! And thanks for the help :)

```
    ROUND (wooper_qtyrcv - lag(wooper_qtyrcv) OVER (PARTITION BY wo_id ORDER BY wooper_seqnumber)) as difference
```